# Native C# .NET method to check if item exists in collection before adding

Tags: c#, collections

I find myself writing this quite frequently.

```
Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
string key = "hahahahaahaha";
string value = "this value";
if (!h.Contains(key))
{
    h.Add(key, value);
}
```

Is there a native method (perhaps something like AddIf() ??) that checks to see if it exists in the collection and if it does not, adds it to the collection? So then my example would change to:

```
Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
string key = "hahahahaahaha";
string value = "this value";
h.AddIf(key, value);
```

This would apply beyond a Hastable. Basically any collection that has a .Add method.

EDIT: Updated to add a value when adding to the Hashtable :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, you probably don't write *that* code, because [`Hashtable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) uses key/value pairs, not just keys.

If you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, I suggest you use [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx), and then you can just unconditionally call [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353005.aspx) - the return value will indicate whether it was actually added or not.

EDIT: Okay, now we know you're talking about key/value pairs - there's nothing built-in for a conditional add (well, there is in `ConcurrentDictionary` IIRC, but...), but if you're happy to overwrite the existing value, you can just use the indexer:

```
h[key] = value;
```

Unlike `Add`, that won't throw an exception if there's already an entry for the key - it'll just overwrite it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jon and you're correct. I was working with a Hashtable and was using keys AND values. When I went to write this question I got ahead of myself :)

Comment: @rodey: So do you need to check for the value being the same?

Comment: My question wasn't specific to the Hashtable. It could be a Hashtable, Dictionary, List, etc. The collections I mentioned all have a .Add method and that's where I wanted to know if something like a AddIf existed for these collections.

Comment: @rodey: But they behave very differently - see my edit, for example. That's appropriate for a `Hashtable` or `Dictionary`, but not a `List`. Then there's `HashSet` which is different again. In other words, the right solution *is* specific to the type in question.

Answer (score 8):

There isn't such a method in the .NET framework. But you can easily write your own extension method:

```
public static void AddIfNotExists<T>(this ICollection<T> coll, T item) {
    if (!coll.Contains(item))
        coll.Add(item)
}
```

For IDictionary, I use this method (generally for `Dictionary<TKey, List<TValue>>` and variations):

```
public static TValue AddIfNotExists<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, TKey key)
    where TValue : new()
{
    TValue value;
    if (!dict.TryGetValue(key, out value))
    {
        value = new T();
        dict.Add(key, value);
    }
    return value;
}
```

Comment: +1 In addition make sure that equals/hash is defined for the type as to offer expected contains behavior, unless the same reference is all that is cared about.

Answer (score 2):

For a hashtable you could write `myHashtable[key] = myHashtable[key] ?? newValue` where the right hand side would first check if `myHashtable[key]` evaluated to null and if not resolve to that otherwise resolve to `newVale`

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't make sense, since a HashTable needs both a key and a value.

If you meant a `HashSet<T>`, calling `Add` will do nothing if the item is already there.

If you meant a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, you can write `dict[key] = value`, which will add the key if it's not present or overwrite it if it is.

Comment: You are correct. I got ahead of myself when writing the example. I updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

So far it doesn't .But you could write your own extension method to wrap this in one single line.

Answer (score 0):

I often write a similar method in my custom Dictionary/Hashtable collections, as a 
  `Type FetchOrCreate(Key)`,  not as an `void AddIf(Key)`